# Can GitHub Enterprise Hosted on AWS Have Multiple Hostnames

Tags: github-enterprise

Can Github  Enterprise have 2 hostnames (1 hostname for external facing IP and 1 hostname for "internal" facing IP). We have Github Enterprise setup in AWS (on external IP) and we want to save cost as traffic via external IP is expensive (compared to Direct Connect).

So can we have another internal facing hostname in the Github Enterprise setup for people inside the company to do git manipulation (pull, commit, clone, CI/CD operations, etc) so that some of the traffic will be off-loaded to cheaper AWS Direct Connect?